# What are these windows? .. "M" and "Default IME" (from GetWindowText)

Tags: c++, title

Using EnumWindows and GetWindowText, I see many titles with "M' and "Default IME".
What is their primary function?.. It seems to be something quite fundamental.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure about the "M" one, but the "Default IME" window is created by the default Input Method Editor (IME).

An IME allows the user to enter characters in a script that may involve a number of separate keystrokes, e.g. Chinese or Korean.

Different IMEs can be installed via the Region and Language dialogs in Control Panel.

Its not unusual for a number of hidden windows to exist on Windows, especially when there are COM components running (for example, a single threaded [STA] apartment uses a window message pump to serialize actions).